# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]

Tags: php, debugging

I'm trying to build a to-do list using php. I've been following the video by phpacademy, but I was stopped by this bug. So far, I've changed my php.ini folder directory for a Unix socket, also, I restarted Apache after doing this.
I also tried to change the php.ini file in my Xamp folder. Both of these methods have not worked. I also tried changing the connection to the mysql server by adding 'try' and 'catch' in my init.php folder(These weren't used in the tutorial).

init.php

```
  <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['users'] = 1;
$username = "root";
$password = " ";
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=todo", $username, $password);

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'app/init.php' ;

$itemsQuery = $db->prepare("
    SELECT id, name, done
    FROM items
    WHERE user = :user
");

$itemsQuery -> execute( [ 
    'user' => $_SESSION['user_id']
    ]);
$items = $itemsQuery ->rowCount() ? $itemsQuery : [];

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item['name'], '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: My answer about the space in your password is not relevant anymore. As far as I know these are authentication errors. Usually the errors have more information in them, try having `error_reporting(E_ALL);` above your script.

Comment: Okay thank you. The error is still the same though

Comment: See php doc abt pdo::rowcount(): don't use it for select queries  (though it seems to work for MySQL, it's not documented for this use and not portable on other DBs). Keep it for update/delete/... queries.

Comment: Does phpmyadmin succeed connecting your base with the given host, port, db, user and pass?

Comment: The full error is the following Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\To-do\app\init.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\website\To-do\app\init.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql: host=127...', 'root', '') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\website\To-do\Index.php(3): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\To-do\app\init.php on line 8

Comment: The password that I entered allowed me to connect to phpmyadmin, but I guess it isn't letting me connect on this file?